# AspectJ - pointcut on native method call

Tags: java, aop, native, aspectj

Is it possible to set pointcut on native method call with AspectJ? I tried following aspect:

```
public aspect EmailAspect {
    pointcut conn() : call(* java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(..));
    before() : conn() {
        System.out.println("Connecting");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I also didn't find much relevant info via googling (except this http://blog.jayway.com/2007/02/16/static-mock-using-aspectj, however it's not clear if it's possible & how to do it).

I tried to debug my test code (which only connects to some TCP localhost port) in Eclipse and eclipse stopped at socketConnect() breakpoint.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

This is probably the cause:

[AspectJ - Load-time weaving, privileged aspect and pointcut on private method of JRE class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269097/aspectj-load-time-weaving-privileged-aspect-and-pointcut-on-private-method-of)

Answer (score 2):

PlainSocketImpl is in a jar provided by the JDK, right?  You may find the question about [weaving into jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853292/spring-aspectj-compile-time-weaving-external-jar) helpful.  Apparently after you weave in your aspect, you need to remember to run using the woven jars rather than the original.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I don't want to use source code weaving because I don't want to include whole JDK in my compiled code (I use load-time weaving). I think the problem is that socketConnect() is package private and aspect is not privileged.

Comment: @batto That sounds like a likely culprit.  Apologies, I've plenty of aspect theory but not the practical experience.

Answer (score 1):

If [this e-mail](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg04072.html) is true, once a method is declared native, Java will write bytecode that jumps directly to the underlying C++/C machine code. This means there is nothing to intercept for AspectJ, regardless whether it is compile time, post-compile time, or load-time weaving.

Comment: It really seems to be true. I tested it myself. The aspect proposed in email worked for me.