# AspectJ - Load-time weaving, privileged aspect and pointcut on private method of JRE class

Tags: java, aop, private, aspectj

I'm trying to set pointcut on private method java.net.AbstractSocketImpl.connectToAddress(..) and I want to use load-time weaving. This is my test code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable {
        new java.net.Socket("localhost", 10111);
    }
}
```

and this is my privileged aspect:

```
privileged aspect PrivAspect {
    before() : call(* java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(..)) {
        System.out.println("It works");
    }
}
```

and this is META-INF/aop.xml

```
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="PrivAspect"/>
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose -Xset:weaveJavaPackages=true"/>
</aspectj>
```

This is how I compile code:

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java -jar ../lib/aspectjtools-1.6.11.jar -source 6 -cp .:$CLASSPATH PrivAspect.aj
[warning] this affected type is not exposed to the weaver: java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl (needed for privileged access) [Xlint:typeNotExposedToWeaver]

/home/batto/work/ajtest/test/PrivAspect.aj:2 [warning] advice defined in PrivAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]


2 warnings
$ java -cp .:$CLASSPATH -javaagent:../lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar Main
```

The last line throws expected "connection refused" exception (port is closed) but advice is not invoked.

What's the problem?

Thank you.

EDIT: I know that java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(..) is called (I debugged Main in Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like post compile-time weaving with reference to a class not specified on the inpath (java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl). It is necessary to specify explicitly which .class/.jar files are to be "woven" by AspectJ. See more details here: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html

Comment: I want to weave at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: This telling me that privileged aspects and LTW are not compatible, even though the AspectJ documentation does not explicitly says so.